# How to get custom html tag attribute value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How would I store the value  of a custom html element in a variable when the specific element has been clicked.

I've got numerous elements of the same class where the custom html attribute changes for each element and I want to know which one has been clicked.

```
<div class="comment-post-btn comment-post-btn-wrapper" data-comment-id="' . $row['Id'] . '" >
    Post
</div>
<div class="comment-post-btn comment-post-btn-wrapper" data-comment-id="' . $row['Id'] . '" >
    Post
</div>
<div class="comment-post-btn comment-post-btn-wrapper" data-comment-id="' . $row['Id'] . '" >
    Post
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('.comment-post-btn').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).attr('data-comment-id'); // your attribute
});
```

since your attribute starts with `data` you can use `data()` as well:

```
$('.comment-post-btn').click(function(){
   var id = $(this).data('comment-id'); // your attribute
});
```

[jQuery.com(.data())](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: or `.data('comment-id')`

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you

```
$(".comment-post-btn").click(function(){
  var value = $(this).attr("data-comment-id");
  alert(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$( ".yourClass" ).click(function() {
console.log($(this));
});
```

Take a look what is happend in the console of your browser.